# How do i downgrade expo version?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have learned react-native expo lately.

I used expo 38.0.3ver but i use expo 39.0.0.ver now.
(yesterday i updated it.)

Q1.
I wanna downgrade expo version from 39.0.0 to 38.0.3.

So, I think that I will remove node_module directory and run npm install. Is this what I should be doing?

Q2.
I uploaded apk file using expo 38.0.3 version on Google playstore 3 days ago.

If Q1 is correct, is there no problem that buil the apk to update on Playstore app if key store value is same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you'd like to downgrade it.

Q1 - Yes

Q2 - Yes, you can upload it. However, you can double-check with 38.0.3 which has API level is more than 28. otherwise, you will be blocked from November. FYI here is timeline. https://developer.android.com/distribute/play-policies